# How do I convert XML to string and get the element value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, string

How do I convert XML to string and get the element value?

**Example XML**

```
<Example>
  <Option1>x</Option1>
  <Option2>y</Option2>
  <Option3>z</Option3>
</Example>
```

.

If i wanted to get

option1 it would return x,

option2 returns y,

option3 returns z.

etc....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to do it:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

class Test {
    static void Main ()
    {
        string s = "<Example> <Option1>x</Option1> <Option2>y</Option2> <Option3>z</Option3></Example>";
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument (); 
        doc.LoadXml (s);
        XmlNode n = doc.SelectSingleNode ("Example/Option1");
        Console.WriteLine (n.InnerText);
    }
}
```

This will print **x**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq on XDocument to query the xml